# .htaccess fails to serv images and css

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have migrated my wordpress pages to a new server, which is causing my webpages not to load the CSS files and Images files correctly any more.

You can see the webpage here:
http://vetsupply-bronze.webfactory365.com/

As far as i see, when i try to open a css or image, the server automatically adds the url twice like:
http://vetsupply-bronze.webfactory365.com/vetsupply-bronze.webfactory365.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/patient-219x141.jpg

The .htaccess file looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Anyone seeing what is going wrong? - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it's your `.htaccess` that's causing this behaviour.

My guess based on your source is that your configured URL in WordPress does not include `http://` and causes this behaviour.

If you look at your source you see a lot of urls that miss the `http://` prefix.

Could you check your settings (either defined in wp-config.php or defined in your admin interface)?

If you can't access the admin interface, you could add this to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: I can't access the admin interface because of the missing css files. do you know what i should look for in the wp-config file?